# SQL Server concurrent 5 timestamps in a columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I would like to get an SQL Query that would help me to fetch the times in a row whichever lies with in 5 minutes and the count of times noticed should greater than or equal to 5?

For Example:

```
Column A
17:22:23
17:44:31
17:25:36
17:24:11
17:47:39
17:26:22
17:22:44
```

My results should fetch the below values only?

```
17:22:23
17:25:36
17:24:11
17:26:22
17:22:44
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: above SQL Server 2008. SQL Server 2012 also works fine for me Martin

Comment: So 2012 then?Also why aren't `17:44:31` and `17:47:39` shown? They are within 5 minutes of each other?

Comment: Yes it should be fetched as well. didnt see while making that example. But the exact ask is to fetch something that lies 5 mins between each other and has repeated more than 5 times

Comment: Sorry Martin. Was not clear with my Question earlier. Have rephrased it again. Need timestamps that are observed with in 5 minutes and the number of occurence should be more than or equal to 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the exact ask is to fetch something that lies 5 mins between each
>   other and has repeated more than 5 times

This should do it

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                KeepPreceding = IIF(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,  LAG(ColumnA, 4) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA), ColumnA) <= +5, 1, 0),
                KeepFollowing = IIF(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LEAD(ColumnA, 4) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA), ColumnA) >= -5, 1, 0)
         FROM   YourTable),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                /*If at least one of the 4 following rows or this one has the KeepPreceding flag then preserve this row*/
                MAX(KeepPreceding) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 4 FOLLOWING) AS KeptForPreceding,
                /*If at least one of the 4 preceding rows or this one has the KeepFollowing flag then preserve this row*/
                MAX(KeepFollowing) OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS KeptForFollowing
         FROM   T1)
SELECT ColumnA
FROM   T2
WHERE  1 IN ( KeptForPreceding, KeptForFollowing )
ORDER  BY ColumnA;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag` and `lead` as below:

```
SELECT [ColumnA]
FROM   (SELECT [ColumnA],
               PrevVal = LAG([ColumnA]) OVER (ORDER BY [ColumnA]),
               NextVal = LEAD([ColumnA]) OVER (ORDER BY [ColumnA])
        FROM   YourTable) a
WHERE  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PrevVal, [ColumnA]) <= 5
        OR DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [ColumnA], NextVal) <= 5;
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Will give a try and get back. Thanks for the response guys